# Collapse of the AMOC - effects

Tags: oceanography, climatology, thermohaline-circulation

What are the potential effects of an eventual collapse of the Atlantic meridional overturning circulation (AMOC)?

I often see news viting everything ranging from droughts in India to increased climate change deniers' hair loss.

However, I cannot find a definitive reference on the effects of the overturning circulation halt.

Does anyone feel like describing the big picture and pointing me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, its bad news for Europe and North America (and the rest of the world).

The AMOC transports warm water from the equator up towards the North pole and cold waters from the north pole towards the equator. This is an important factor in regulating the climate of North America and Europe.

Its very difficult to say exactly when or what will happen (we need more data) but its likely that when/if the AMOC collapses the northern hemisphere will go into an ice age. An AMOC collapse will also result in increased drought in some areas while others will have increased flooding. This will result in more disease and mass migrations of animals.

Here is a reliable source: https://www.whoi.edu/oceanus/feature/whats-happening-with-the-amoc/

Comment: "its likely that when/if the AMOC collapses the northern hemisphere" - doesn't quite make sense, I think some words are missing - but I'm not sure what, hence can't edit.